# Need a database design advice - query vs. additional column

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have following tables:

```
Customer(customer_id) - 1000 rows (1000 customers)
Invoice(invoice_id, customer_id) - 1000000 rows (1000 invoices per customer)
Charge(charge_id, invoice_id, charge_amount) - 20000000 rows (20 charges per invoice)
```

Now, I am trying to produce a customer's invoice with it's total charge amount.
The resulting table would look something like this:

```
Customer_name | invoice_id | charge_total
    test             1          $1000
    test             2          $1200
    test             3          $900
    ...
```

My question is, what is the best practice for database design for this case?
I am pondering over two options below:

1. Just run everything through a query?
2. Add "charge_total" column in Invoice table to save query processing time (20 times faster)

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to look at this question.  The database purist will say that derived or computed data is redundant and violates 3rd Normal Form.  This is a concern in transactional systems where data is being edited, since normalization prevents you from falling into the trap of having self-conflicting data.

On the other hand, there is a practical view which says that data which is written once and never updated is not subject to update and delete anomalies anyway, so redundancy costs disk space, but is not otherwise a risk.

As a rule, I always design databases to be normalized first and then introduce redundancy on a limited basis, after careful examination of the competing risks.

Comment: This is a "religious-war" type of issue clearly, but I disagree with your assertion that a very high hurdle is required.  The rules for normalization are not scriptural, they are _rules of thumb_ for avoiding common, stupid mistakes that people frequently make and which get them into trouble more often than not.  If you understand the _why_ of the rule of thumb and assess the situation on those merits, then the rule of thumb itself is no longer of use.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. 
yes, I will wait until I come across performance issues.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to answer - do you *know* that you have a performance problem? I'd not optimize unless I really, really had to. 
And even then, I would consider an "invoice archive" table to hold the computed values. Logically, there's nothing wrong in calculating summaries and storing them in a table to reflect the amount that was actually invoiced - including tax, shipping etc. This means you can store an archive version of the invoice data without having to worry about.

I'd not want to store it in the main "invoice" table unless invoices are immutable - you create it, and nothing ever changes from the moment it's created. That doesn't work if you have a business process in which invoices are created in advance and items are added to it over time.

Answer (score 0):

This decision comes down to the tradeoff of speed for your users vs additional complexity in your database that makes your code more susceptible to errors. It reminds me of this discussion:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211414/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

In your case, since you've already done the performance testing, I feel like denormalizing your database like you suggest is a good thing.

Comment: I don't believe he has done performance testing. He is just guessing.

Comment: -1 There needs to be a *very* high hurdle for "denormalization". I don't think the fact that the OP says "20 times faster" means that he's actually done performance testing, just that he's making performance *assumptions*.

Comment: My bad... I did infer from his statement of "20 times faster" that he has actually done performance testing. I can see where you're coming from now. If it hadn't been a guess, would my answer have still deserved a downvote?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you want to keep in mind, is how often does the data change that would affect the value of "charge_total"? For example, if an item is returned, does that charge get taken off the invoice at a later date? If things do change often, you'll have to keep in mind the overhead of having those change events responsible for updating the "charge_total" field.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check if the performance without an additional column is sufficient in your case. If it is not, then, and not before (!), you should check if your "20 times faster" guess is really correct. Try to add a View to your database for your `charge_total` and test how your DB system handles that view. I don't know MySql enough, but some modern DB systems are able to do internal caching of view data as long as the source data does not change.

When you have done that, and you are sure the additional column `charge_total` is a solution for a problem you really have, then you should make sure that those redundant data is hold consistent. You can do this on the DB side (using triggers), or on the client side  - when you have the one-and-only process that changes the `charges` table under your control.

Answer (score -1):

Making `charge_total` a calculated column in the `invoice` table would probably be the easiest way I can think of. It would save you from doing that calculation each time you ran the query to get the values, which I'm assuming happens more frequently that adding a charge.

Comment: -1. Optimizing without knowing the performance requirements is pure evil.

Answer (score -3):

Nowadays disk space is cheap so you do not have to worry about size. If the extra column improves the performance, just go with it.

Comment: -1. Optimizing without knowing the performance requirements is pure evil.

Comment: No actually not improving performance of your code denotes laziness. The question as it was implied the possibility of placing a new column or not so from any point of view an improvement in performance is a good choice. Though is easier to criticize then to actually reply with a helpful answer :)

Comment: IMHO not improving performance of code which has no need for better performance is the *right kind of laziness*. And when it comes to DB design, to my experience, redundant data has a very high risk that it will cause problems sooner or later.

Comment: Yes .. this is why todays software has the same performance as 10 years ago software considering that computer power grew hmms let's say a few hundred times. Back to the point, there are 2 kinds of redundant data. In this case the redundant data never changes. So the risk on inconsistencies is limited to writing a bad insert statement which can happen with or without the redundant field. Normalizing data is a good practice, but not always. Most of the times normalizing to the maximum will give huge performance issues in some situations.

Comment: I agree when the data never changes, then an additional column wont mind (but where did you gain that knowledge that this is the case here?) And  "same performance as 10 years ago software" - repeating that urban legend again and again does not make it true. Here is a counter example: http://science.slashdot.org/story/10/12/24/2327246/Progress-In-Algorithms-Beats-Moores-Law.

Comment: Well .. the charge_total is on invoice and one invoice is written at once and in one transaction (basic accounting). And about algorithm improvements, there were probably breakthroughs in algorithms, yes, but not in the code the programmer writes day to day. I agree that some great guys wrote nice NN algorithms, nice GA algorithms, or graphic algorithms. But how many programmers use them at the end. In my office the most common code is LINQ with BIG where's, counts, tops and whatever. While you write it in 2 minutes and the productivity is great, the performance is at best mediocre.

Comment: If you would have written your conclusions about the immutability of the data in your answer, I probably would not have downvoted it.